# Discrepancy between SHAP Contributions and Predictions in Binary Classification with tidymodels and XGBoost

Tags: r, xgboost, predict, tidymodels, shap

I have developed a binary prediction model in R using the tidymodels library with the boost_tree algorithm (XGBoost). Subsequently, I used the shap.values function from the SHAPforxgboost package and performed predictions. SHAP calculates the individual contributions of each variable in a way that, when summed and added to the BIAS, should equal the prediction value.

However, I am encountering an issue where the prediction value does not match the sum of variable contributions plus the BIAS. Below, I provide an example of the code. At the end, I compared the prediction values with the values obtained using shap.values, both for the first and last records. The values do not match. However, when I use a model with a continuous dependent variable, the sum of contributions matches the prediction value.

Could someone please help me understand how to make shap.values calculate the individual contributions of each record and variable in a way that, when summed with the BIAS contributions, corresponds to the prediction value?

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(SHAPforxgboost)

# Database 
binaryDatabase <- iris %>% 
  mutate(
    Class = ifelse(
      test = (Sepal.Length > median(Sepal.Length)),
      yes = "yes",
      no = "no"
    ) %>% 
      factor(
        levels = c(
          "yes", "no"
        )
      )
  ) %>% 
  select(-Sepal.Length, -Species)
  
# Model
model <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(
    recipe = recipe(
      formula = Class ~ .,
      data = binaryDatabase
    )
  ) %>% 
  add_model(
    spec = boost_tree(
      mode = "classification",
      trees = 33L,
      min_n = 2L,
      tree_depth = 4L,
      learn_rate = 0.0331,
      loss_reduction = 0.0000000436,
      sample_size = 0.342
    ) %>% 
      set_engine(
        engine = "xgboost",
        objective = "binary:logistic",
        eval_metric = "aucpr",
        nthread = (parallel::detectCores() - 1)
      )
  ) %>% 
  fit(
    data = binaryDatabase
  )


# Predict
predictSepal.Length <- predict(
  model,
  binaryDatabase,
  type = "prob"
)

# SHAP
shapModel <- shap.values(
  xgb_model = extract_fit_engine(model),
  X_train = binaryDatabase %>% 
    select(-Class) %>% 
    as.matrix()
)

# 
shapScore <- shapModel$shap_score %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    BIAS = shapModel$BIAS0$BIAS
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    ProbYes = rowSums(.)
  )

# Prob predict yes first record
predictSepal.Length$.pred_yes[1]

# Sun scores first record
shapScore$ProbYes[1]

# Prob predict yes last record
predictSepal.Length$.pred_yes[150]

# Sun scores last record
shapScore$ProbYes[150]
```

Comment: SHAP values are on "raw" logit scale. They cannot be mapped to probability scale without violating fairness axioms.